# Filling template textTab, how to wrap text value?

Tags: docusignapi

I'm using a template with a bunch of standard text fields defined via the browser UI placing fields on a document background. I've selected the "fixed" option for each of these fields, however the text when programmatically filled in via an api call is not wrapping and instead extending outside the prescribed area. How can i have this programmatic value entry of fields but still have them respect the width of the field?

Have tried setting the "fixed" attribute on the field in the template definition UI.

I won't paste the full json I'm passing as it's huge, but I'm using the same tabLabel/value format from the DocuSign example as seen here:

```
{
    "accountId": "301424",
    "emailSubject": "API Example - Populating Data in Templates",
    "templateId": "44D9E888-3D86-4186-8EE9-7071BC87A0DA",
    "templateRoles": [{
        "email": "john.doe@email.com",
        "name": "John Doe",
        "roleName": "Customer",
        "tabs": {
            "textTabs": [{
                "tabLabel": "CustomerAddress",
                "value": "123 Main St. San Francisco, CA 94105"
            }, 
            {
                "tabLabel": "CustomerSSN",
                "value": "12-345-6789"
            }]
        }
    }],
    "status": "sent"
}
```

Expected result would be a wrapped text in the field, however am actually getting text running into subsequent fields:

What I've defined in the template:
[image: TextField Definition in DocuSign UI]

What I'm getting in the output (obviously not ideal):
[image]

Answer (score 0):

For text fields (text tabs) if you want multiple lines give the field a larger height to enable two (or more) lines of text. The text should wrap automatically.

The height a line of text takes up depends on the text size for the field, which you can set.

You're setting the initial value via the API--will the signer be able to change it? That's a common use case for setting the initial values--enable the signer to update/correct the data as needed. (And DocuSign will tell your app whether the signer changed the value or not.)

If you're setting the value of the field and the signer can **not** change the value, then you're using using DocuSign as a custom document (not form) generator. That's fine, many apps do that.

If you run into an issue that DocuSign doesn't support then an alternative is to create the custom document using a different technique.

For example, you could create the document in HTML (programmatically) and DocuSign will convert it to a PDF for signing. Or you can create a customized PDF
document yourself, there are many libraries available.